# How to include eps files in Plain TeX?

Tags: graphics, tex-core, plain-tex, eps

The title stands for itself.

If it is not possible, how does LaTeX import an EPS file using `\includegraphics`?

Comment: Quite doable, of course. Are we allowed to use `miniltx`/`eplain`?

Comment: @JosephWright Whatever it takes :D

Comment: The reason for asking is that you can of course copy-paste the code, but the LaTeX `graphics` does some work to do the inclusion and it's not really that useful to repeat this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a package `epsf.tex` by Tom Rokicki.  Try

```
\input epsf

\epsfbox{myfile.eps}

\bye
```

Reading the file epsf.tex (in my system it is `/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/epsf/epsf.tex`) will give you an insight into the way TeX works with postscript graphics.

Answer (score 11):

The LaTeX package `graphicx` also can be used in plain TeX with the help of `miniltx.tex`.
For driver `dvips.def` there is already a TeX file that can be loaded:

```
\input graphicx.tex
\includegraphics{myimage.eps}
```

The file `graphicx.tex` contains:

```
\input miniltx

\def\Gin@driver{dvips.def}
\input graphicx.sty

\resetatcatcode
```

Usually the TeX distribution has an intelligent `graphics.cfg` that can detect some of the drivers (pdfTeX/LuaTeX, XeTeX) and sets a default driver (usually `dvips`) otherwise, then

```
\input miniltx.tex
\input graphicx.sty
\resetatcatcode
```

would be enough and the the driver definition is only needed, if other DVI drivers are
used. (Also other LaTeX packages can be used in plain TeX, e.g. `ifpdf`, `ifxetex`, ...).